# How can I tie together a jQuery object and a selector?

Tags: jquery

I have the following where $form is a jQuery object.

```
var $form  = oSubmit.$form;
```

On this form I have input elements with a class of update-grid.

```
        $('input.update-grid')
            .each(function () {
                var id = this.id.replace('modal', '');
                $('#input' + id).val(this.value)
            })
```

How can I tie these two together so that the function works on each input.update-grid on the $form object?

Comment: `$form.find('input.update-grid')` or `$form.children('input.update-grid')` maybe

Answer (score 3):

Use the object in `$form` as context :

```
$('input.update-grid', $form).each(function(index, elem) {
    var id = elem.id.replace('modal', '');
    $('#input' + id).val(elem.value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('input.update-grid', $form).each(...)
```

which is actually just a wrapper for:

```
$form.find('input.update-grid').each(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$form.find('input.update-grid').each(function () {`

var id = this.id.replace('modal', '');

$('#input' + id).val(this.value)

})